# What do you call the use of the phrase 'to open one's mouth' to mean 'to talk'?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

> He opened his mouth.

Is there a term for using the idiom above to mean 'he talked'?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please [clarify your specific problem](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *Anticipation*.

Comment: _Open one's mouth_ means: to speak or start to speak.

Comment: Is this your question:  Is there a label for expressions that hint strongly at what they mean without actually saying it?  This one means nervy speech. "He opened his mouth, with no right to address me to begin with." "She opened a mouth, and I've never heard such loud, foul language."

Comment: The difference between the *exact, literal* meaning and the *intended* meaning is so small here that I don't think you could reasonably say it's a ***metaphoric*** usage. So I'd say it's just a form of *[stylistic, idiomatic] [**circumlocution***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circumlocution).

Answer (score 4):

If we say  "finally he opened his mouth" in place of "he talked", it has a disapproving or offensive tone. Figuratively such a usage is called "dysphemism".

[dysphemism](http://www.synonym.com/synonyms/dysphemism) (n.)
an offensive or disparaging expression that is substituted for an inoffensive one.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Mahmud Koya's excellent answer. This is a disparaging idiom. You would never really use it to simply mean "someone began to speak". It's almost always used with a negative connotation.

If you wanted to put a positive spin on it in an idiomatic way you could say something like: "finally he began to *speak up*". This would be like saying they finally began to voice their position or concerns. But its meaning is different than saying, "finally he began to open his mouth".

The phrase "opened his mouth" is almost always used negatively.

In English we use the concept of ones mouth being open, closed, shut, etc... to mean various things. As in, "if you have nothing nice to say then keep your mouth shut". Which simply means, unless you can say something nice then you should not speak. Or, "open one's mouth". Hopefully that helps explain how and why it has a negative connotation.